# Angular 2 - error when pushing to array to be displayed with *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, google-geocoder

I want to display a list of items I received through the Google Geocoder in Angular 2 (specifically Ionic 2) with *ngFor.

address-modal.html

```
<ion-content class="address-modal">
  <ion-searchbar id="pac" [(ngModel)]="searchQuery" (input)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="#address of addresses">
      {{ address }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

address-modal.ts

```
import {Page, NavController, ViewController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {ViewChild} from 'angular2/core';

declare var google: any;


@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/address-modal/address-modal.html',
})
export class AddressModal {

  searchQuery: string = '';
  geocoder: any;
  addresses: any = [];

  constructor(public nav: NavController, public view: ViewController) {
    this.geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  }

  getItems(searchbar) {

    this.geocoder.geocode({ 'address': searchbar.value }, function (results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        console.log('len ' + results.length);
        console.log(results);

        for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          this.addresses.push(results.formatted_address);
        }

      } else {
        console.error("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
```

The geocoder returns successfully a list with results, which I display in the console, but Chrome immediately blocks execution and displays the following error:

`address-modal.ts:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addresses' of undefined`

which points to the line

`this.addresses.push(results.formatted_address);`

I would like to display the list of formatted_addresses in my *ngFor block on my template. (I don't want to use Googles' Autocomplete searchbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
function (results, status)
```

to

```
(results, status) =>
```

otherwise `this` won't point to the `AddressModal` instance but instead to the callback function itself.

For more details see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions